# Laravel Not Zero Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm using laravel validation system. And I have a field is database as wholesale_price and price is decimal. For validation I'm using this.

```
'wholesale_price' => 'required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
```

But price cannot be 0. And I have to validate > 0

How can I do that. In laravel min:1 functionality but this is not useful for me. Because I have prices like 0.005 or 0.02

Comment: Use a custom validator. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do `regex` to solve this. Take the following test for example:

```
$input = ["wholesale_price" => 0.005];
$rules = ["wholesale_price" => "numeric|between:0.001,99.99"];
```

As long as your require the `numeric` rule, then `between` will treat the value being validated as a number (`int`, `float`, `double`, etc.) As long as your don't pass a string value such as `$0.001`, or strip any unwanted characters prior to validation, this method will return true for anything above `0` and the max value you set (currently `99.99`, but you can set it as high as you'd like.)

Here's a simple testing template:

```
$input = [
    "price" => 0
];
$input2 = [
    "price" => 0.001
];
$rules = [
    "price" => "numeric|between:0.001,99.99",
];

$validator = \Validator::make($input, $rules);
$validator2 = \Validator::make($input2, $rules);

dd($validator->passes());
// Returns false;

dd($validator2->passes());
// Returns true;
```

Note: Also works if `price` is a string value, just strip the `$` if you're sending that to the server.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks :P Stumbled across the reason why that `numeric` rule is required; if you don't have it, `between` treats the value as a `string`, and checks its `strlen()` value against the rule, so `strlen("0.001")` is `5`, and falls between `0.001 and 99.99`, thus always passing the validation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
/^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/
```

Explanation:

```
^            # Start of string
\s*          # Optional whitespace
(?=.*[1-9])  # Assert that at least one digit > 0 is present in the string
\d*          # integer part (optional)
(?:          # decimal part:
 \.          # dot
 \d{1,2}     # plus one or two decimal digits
)?           # (optional)
\s*          # Optional whitespace
$            # End of string
```

Conclusion:

```
'wholesale_price' => 'required|regex:/^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/',
```